# Reading a CSV file with Russian Text not displaying correctly

Tags: vba, autocad

As someone a bit unfamiliar with VBA, I'm struggling with this one.

It's an AutoCAD macro whereby I'm trying to read a CSV containing both Russian and English.

Below is code, where I am loading in the data and storing within a dictionary.

```
Open FilePath For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
        LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
        english = LCase(LineItems(0))
        russian = LineItems(1)
        translator_dict.add key:=english, Item:=russian
    Loop
Close #1
```

However, I'm finding that the Russian text being loaded in appears to just be random symbols.

I'm no expert, but I guess it's to do with the encoding. However from browsing similar problems, I'm struggling to come up with a solution. Can someone please assist.

Comment: how are you trying to display the results?

Comment: In AutoCAD, I'm just replacing text entities with the Russian text.